# XSLX not downloading properly on IE 8

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, symfony-1.4

I'm currently building a web application for a client. And i can't download an xlsx file with the originale IE8. Whereas it works with the IE8 compatibility mode of IE9.

I'm using symfony 1.4, php 5.2.6. The xslx file is valid.

My code :

```
$this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma: public'); 
    $this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/force-download');
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="Export_Excel.xlsx"');
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Connection', 'close');
    $this->getResponse()->setContent($fileData);
    $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();
    $this->getResponse()->send();
```

IE 8 say it can't download, because he doesn't find the website or it doesn't answer, and to try later. This is not an url problem, because i can display a blank page with the same ulr.

Moreover, this code

```
        session_write_close();
        $this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma: public'); 
        $this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/force-download');
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="Export_Excel.xlsx"');
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Connection', 'close');

      @ob_end_clean();
    flush();


    @readfile(sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir').'/'.$filename.'.xlsx');
  throw new sfStopException();
```

Then the xslx file is downloaded as a zip file. Note the session_write_close(); Because the above code didn't work withouth that.

Any ideas ?

I wish to be able to download my file as a xslx file. (don't have to rename). The first bunch of code works with chrome, firefox, IE 9, IE9 compat IE 8, IE9 compat IE7. But not IE8.

**UPDATE 2:**

So the problem is really in the download part. My boss told me to temporary replace xlsx by csv, and i have the same exact problem to download the file.

So any ideas to make the file download work with IE8 ?

Comment: Are you using apache? If so, [check this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/19060/why-are-docx-xlsx-pptx-downloading-from-webserver-as-zip-files).

Comment: Yes, i am. It seem that my boss used your solution (while i was in vacation), but it didn't work. And i'm not sure that's a bug. All the headers and data in buffer are cleared, before the readfile.                    My problem lies in bunch of code 1, it should work and send file, but IE8 don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is quite simple to understand but very hard to find.

My download was called by javascript with a window.open, like a working pdf export. But in the case of a new window, IE8 ignore the force download and try to display. So it work with pdf. But crash with non displayable extensions.

So the solution is to use a simple link or a window.location.href =, when you need to give dynamic args, like in my case.